# Upload file to Firebase Storage Error 404 - "Not Found. Could not get object"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to select a PDF file and upload to Firebase Storage, unfortunately I keep getting a false success with the following in my console.

Does anybody know what I may be doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

> Selected:
> file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/Documents/document.pdf
>
> Coordinator going away Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain
> Code=-13010 "Object uploads/documents does not exist."
>
> UserInfo={object=uploads/documents, ResponseBody={   "error": {
> "code": 404,
> "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
> "status": "GET_OBJECT"   } },
>
> bucket=name-webapp.appspot.com, data={length = 115, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ...
> 54220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json;
> charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object uploads/documents does
> not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus,
> ResponseErrorCode=404})
>
> uploadImageData: false, none

**Document Picker**

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    var parent: FilePicker

    init( parent1: FilePicker) {
        self.parent = parent1
    }
    
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        print("Selected: \(urls.first!)")
        
        let localFile = urls.first!

        // User reference URL for home/roomIndex/tenancy
        // Pass to FirestoreManager
        let firestoreManager = FirestoreManager()
        
        firestoreManager.uploadFile(localFile: localFile, serverFileName: "filename.pdf") { (isSuccess, url) in
            
            print("uploadImageData: \(isSuccess), \(url ?? "none")")
            
        }

    }
    
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        print("Cancelled")
    }



    deinit {
        print("Coordinator going away")
    }
}
```

**Firebase**

```
func uploadFile(localFile: URL, serverFileName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ url: String?) -> Void) {
    
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
    let directory = "uploads"
    let fileRef = storageRef.child(directory).child("documents")

    _ = fileRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                print("\(error)")
                completionHandler(false, nil)
                return
            }
            // File Uploaded Successfully
            completionHandler(true, downloadURL.absoluteString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you get an error when determining the download URL. You might want to log `error` to see wht the problem is.

Comment: Didn't you post pretty much the same topic several hours ago?  It's hard to figure out how is wrong with your code because you don't show your reference tree.  It seems to me that the following is wrong.  let fileRef = storageRef.child(directory + serverFileName)

Comment: There are a number of things that could be causing that - I agree with @ElTomato as that line looks suspicious. You're missing error checking by force unwrapping optionals and totally ignoring this `metadata, error` as if there's an error - it will just silently fail. You may not have access to storage (not being authenticated) which could also cause the issue. Add some error checking and step through your code line-by line, examining the vars as you go until you spot something that's not what you expect. Update the question with more info an we'll take a look

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen apologies, I have logged the error and include in the original post

Comment: @ElTomato no I did not. I have updated the original post however

Comment: @Jay I have logged the error and updated my question

Comment: That error comes from `fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in` and indicates the the file doesn't exist. It makes most sense that the upload fails, in which case you should be able to find out the cause of that by logging the error from `fileRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it seems I have been a little dumb here, yes you are right I needed to log those errors too. I did not have permissions to access the document, which I needed to enable iCloud documents in capabilities, then I still had an error which was due to .open instead of .import for the document picker.

Comment: Let's consider it a lesson in effectively debugging a complex problem. ;-)   Good to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issued.

First the I logged the error from `fileRef.putFile` which was

> “The file “…” couldn’t be opened because you don’t
> have permission to view it.”

Then I needed to enable iCloud Documents in capabilities. After that the error still persisted and it was due to `.upload` instead of `.import` for the following line.

```
 let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
```